# Postgresql select timestamp for GST(Gulf standard time)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using the below select statement in postgres database and getting error as "Invalid input syntax for type timetstamp:"Wed Sep 04 08:45:15 GST 2019"

```
select * from testtable where created_time >= 'Wed Sep 04 08:45:15 GST 2019"
```

Here the error is reporting related to my timezone region "GST".

If i change the GST to GMT, the query is working fine.

Please note that i have the timezone region as "timezone = 'Asia/Muscat' in my "Postgresql.conf" file.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if `GST` is an available timezone - you can find a list of available time zones from the `pg_timezone_names` view

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html

to check and see if GST exists try:

```
select *
from pg_timezone_names
where abbrev like '%GST%'
or name like '%GST%'
```

Otherwise select something from that list that is there.

Comment: GST is neither a valid timezone name not abbreviation but  'Asia/Muscat'  is a valid timezone name.